# css flexbox not interpreted inside iframe

Tags: css, flexbox

when I put content into iframe the header managing with flexbox has not the same render. Why iframe content different ?
https://codepen.io/lguigo/pen/JmKQEa

```
header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
            border-bottom: 25px solid #f2f2f2;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
        }
```

chrome responsive emulation OK :
[image]

this url inside iframe KO :

[image]

Comment: flex tag : *Ask Question
Apache Flex [NOT CSS FLEXBOX] is a framework for developing Rich Internet Applications that run in Flash Player or Adobe Air. Originally designed by Adobe* --> please read description of tags before using

Comment: `display:flex` is being applied. Looking at the difference between the screenshot and what's in code flex, you are missing some styles on the `h1`. `font-size` perhaps?

Comment: _“chrome responsive emulation OK”_ - add the device type selector, and switch from “mobile” emulation to “desktop”, and it looks the same as in the iframe even in chrome emulation …

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference if its in an iframe or not. the real difference is the width of the container. The iframe is pretty small so the things in the header don't really fit. Try adding a `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the header. At least that will place the element under each other if they can't be next to each other.